# ZF2 Input Filter Change Message Color

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2

I made typical form with ZF2 form and wanted to add validation using ZF2 InputFilter. It was success but the colour of error message is black which is looks strange. I tried to change the colour by using method I've searched like this:

```
array(
    'name'    =>'NotEmpty',
    'options' => array(
        'messages' => array(
            NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => '<div style="color:red;">Please enter User Name!</div>'
        ),
    ),
),
```

But, instead of message's colour changed to red, it showed the  tag with style, in other word, just plain HTML. What is the proper way to achieve my need?

Comment: You realize this is a matter of CSS? Check what class the parent element got and then change the attributes of the CSS-Class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Just inspected the element and found it class is 'input-error', do you mean that I must change its attribute by using  JavaScript?

Comment: No, you use CSS to style the class `input-color` to your desired `color:red`. This has literally nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-inspected the HTML, actually the message generated by InputFilter don't have any CSS class. Just like this: `<ul><li>Please enter User Name!</li></ul>`, what I suppose to do?

Comment: My bad, got too many custom stuff in my projects, don't know about the defaults anymore .. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way would be to modify the view helper ;)

Inside your `module.config.php`

```
'view_helpers' => [
    'factories' => [
        'formelementerrors' => function($vhm) {
            $fee = new \Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElementErrors();
            $fee->setAttributes([
                'class' => 'your error classes'
            ]);
            return $fee;
        }
    ]
]
```

The alternate approach when rendering errors using `$this->formElementErrors()` would be to add the error classes inside the ViewHelper directly

```
$this->formElementErrors($element, ['class' => 'my error classes']);
```

Comment: I added your code in `config/autoload/global.php` because in `module.confing.php` nothing happened. The css class is added, but instead added in `<li>`, it added to `<ul>`, so the message color won't change. It become like this: `<ul class="admin-error-message"><li>Please enter User Name!</li></ul>`. The CSS class just a line of style `color: red`. In Firefox the colour changed, but not in Safari. How to workaround this?

Comment: @yunhasnawa I leave this for yourself to figure out. You now have an error class where you need it. And from that point you can do the rest. If, btw, nothing changed from module.config.php than all the configuration from your module doesn't work. The rest tho is pure CSS and i refuse from helping with that.

Comment: I'am sorry for my lot of question. I just realised that safari didn't load my css so the list colour didn't change. Thank you very much for your really useful help. Best regards.

Comment: No need for apologies ;) It's just with an "error" like you've given me, there was a handful of possible reasons and all come down to simply checking things thoroughly :>